# Add new user in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

I am using VS2005 .NET 2.0 C#.

I am currently referencing to a website on implementing AD user management on asp webpage.

I have seen one method which `adds user to group`.

However, there are some parameters which I do not understand and know what to replace with.

Below is the method provided:

```
public void AddToGroup(string userDn, string groupDn)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn);
        dirEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userDn);
        dirEntry.CommitChanges();
        dirEntry.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //doSomething with E.Message.ToString();

    }
}
```

`userDn` and `groupDn` has been explained but I still do not know what to fill in it

`userDn`: the distinguishedName of the user: `CN=user, OU=USERS, DC=contoso, DC=com`
`groupDn`: the distinguishedName of the group: `CN=group,OU=GROUPS,DC=contoso,DC=com`

May I know what are the 2 parameters and where can I get them from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directory is a tree in wich each object is a node. Each object in this tre as got a Distinguished Name (DN), it looks a bit like the DNS name of a computer. You can have look to your Active-Directory with an LDAP vision using LDP.EXE tool from the ressource kit (or natively installes on W2K8). You'll find here under one LDAP AD vision

[image: LDP vision of an AD]

for

[image: MMC vision of an AD]

How can you find them :

For the group :

```
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dom.fr/dc=dom,dc=fr");
/* Directory Search for a group
 */
DirectorySearcher dsLookForGrp = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookForGrp.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", "yourgroup");
dsLookForGrp.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForGrp.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
SearchResult srcGrp = dsLookForGrp.FindOne();

string groupDN = srcGrp.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
```

For the user :

```
/* Directory Search
 */
DirectorySearcher dsLookForUser = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookForUser.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", YourUser);
dsLookForUser.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForUser.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
dsLookForUser.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName  ");
dsLookForUser.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
SearchResult srcUser = dsLookForUser.FindOne();

string userDN = srcUser .Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
```