# Create a New User in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

So, for a few days i've been trying to do this, still, i've passed trough a few problems but im stuck on this one. looks like my connection to AD is working fine (after alot of digging and googling)
i have this.
I'm not a developer, still i have studied c# in school and i have some knowledge of it, still, i need to make this work in order to save time when it comes the time to create a new user.

```
private void btn_create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            bool valid = false;

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "PTLISDC04", "Users");
            {
                valid = ctx.ValidateCredentials("myadminaccount", "mypassword");
            }


            UserPrincipal usr = new UserPrincipal(ctx);


            usr.UserPrincipalName = tb_user.Text.ToString() + "@kpmg.com";
            usr.Name = tb_lname.Text.ToString() + ", " + lb_fname.Text.ToString() + " " + lbl_mname.Text.ToString();
            usr.Description = tb_empid.Text.ToString();
            usr.EmailAddress = tb_email.Text.ToString();
            usr.DisplayName = tb_lname.Text.ToString() + ", " + lb_fname.Text.ToString() + " " + lbl_mname.Text.ToString();
            usr.Save();

            usr.Dispose();
            ctx.Dispose();

            MessageBox.Show("User Created!");
```

and when i press the "create user" button i get this:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException'
>   occurred in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
>
> Additional information: An invalid dn syntax has been specified.

and it points to this line on code

```
usr.UserPrincipalName = tb_user.Text.ToString() + "@kpmg.com";
```

if i comment this line it goes to the next and so on

Comment: Please check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936438/add-new-user-in-active-directory?rq=1 looks like a duplicate

Comment: hum, not much, i'm using System.DirectoryServices that just exist in .net 3.5 or 4.5 +. And he was using Visual Studio 2005 :p 
I think i am using something a little bit more advanced and the syntax is different too
(not sure if i made myself clear but i think i did)

Comment: What is the value of this string `tb_user.Text.ToString()`?

Comment: @Bruzum it's like a username. so imagine that my name is Robert Del, the username is like "rdel" or "robertdel".